# Besides mechanical failure, what other systems have failed/deteriorated on Yutu?

Tags: the-moon, lunar-landing, yutu

Yutu was ferried to Luna by way of [Chang`e](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chang%27e_3) in December 2013

The Wikipedia article on the mission writes to say the mission duration for the lander, and rover were as follows.

- Lander: 1 Year
- Rover: 3 months

After Lunar land-fall on December 14th 2013 ADG, Yutu purportedly suffered a mechanical failure in January leaving it immobile within sight of the Lander.

[This report](http://www.spacedaily.com/reports/Chinese_lunar_rover_alive_but_weak_999.html) writes to say

> Its functionality has been weakened considerably by the bitterly cold lunar nights after the rover experienced a "mechanical control abnormality" in January

The same report writes further to say

> "With each lunar night, the functionality of Yutu is yet again weakened"

The Wikipedia article for Yutu lists the following systems/instruments

- Ground Penetrating Radar
- Spectrometer

  - Alpha
  - Infra-red
- Camera Pair

  - Navigation
  - Hazard
  - Panoramic

Besides the twin mechanical failures leaving Yutu immobile and it's Solar Panels unable to lock-down - what other instruments/systems aboard the rover have suffered degradation/demise over the last 7-odd months?